# In Dart must element.html(" ") occur within the context of a body tag?

Tags: dart, dart-html

```
TableElement table = new TableElement();
document.body.children.add(table);
table.children.add(new Element.html("<tr><td>test</td></tr>"));
```

The above code snippet returns the error: "Uncaught Bad state: No element". Reading the API docs on the DartLang website this is because when using the Element.html(" ") constructor, "the HTML fragment is parsed as if it occurred within the context of a <body> tag". Therefore, we would need to write:

```
new Element.html("<table><tr><td>test</td></tr></table>")
```

However, reading "dart in action" Chris Buckett uses this exact same syntax when building a table.

Has something changed or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a browser "feature". A `<tr>` element can't exist on its own and is just dropped from the HTML when it finds one.

The docs to `new Element.html()` says

> Creates an HTML element from a valid fragment of HTML.

Alternatively you can use

```
  table.append(
      new TableRowElement()..append(new TableCellElement()..text = 'test'));
```

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/12ea44d3c2a2935bc74d9d17baa8610a)